# Spring Exception evaluating SpringEL expression

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm stuck on my project, I have a seemingly identical setup on another page on my website but I cannot get this one to work.

DemoApplication.java

```
@GetMapping("/generate")
    public String GenerateForm(Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("RecipeGenerator", new RecipeGenerator());
          return "generate";
    }
    @PostMapping("/generate")
    public String GenerateSubmit(@ModelAttribute RecipeGenerator recipegenerator) throws IOException {
        recipegenerator.execute();
        System.out.println(recipegenerator.getContent());
        return "generate_result";   
    }
```

Here I can get out any value from my method recipegenerator.execute but it's not visible on my html page generate_result, I get this error:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "recipegenerator.content" (template: "generate_result" - line 11, col 10)

My HTML, generate_result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Recipes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<p><b><a th:text="${recipegenerator.content}" ></a></b></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In model, the attribute name is RecipeGenerator (R in caps). But in html `<p><b><a th:text="${recipegenerator.content}" ></a></b></p>`, the case is different. That might be an issue

Comment: It's actually `recipeGenerator`. You can decide what name the attribute has by using `@ModelAttribute(name = "whatever")`.

Comment: Thanks, when using recipeGenerator it works... but I still don't really understand why, should it not be RecipeGenerator? recipeGenerator is not mentioned anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Your corresponding view would need access to the object.  So in your method mapped with `@PostMapping`, you would need/want:

```
@PostMapping("/generate")
public String generateSubmit(@ModelAttribute RecipeGenerator recipeGenerator, Model model) throws IOException { //add model param
    recipeGenerator.execute();
    model.addAttribute("content", recipeGenerator.getContent()); //need this and assumes it would return a value
    System.out.println(recipeGenerator.getContent()); //use a logger if you can instead
    return "generate_result";   
}
```

Then in your HTML:

`<p><strong><a th:text="${content}">[Some Link]</a></strong></p>`

Also:

I would highly recommend the Java-style convention of camel case for consistency since the next programmer reading and implementing your code may produce errors with regard to case sensitivity.  So, `recipeGenerator` would make sense, except of course for the class name.

Note that `<b>` tags are deprecated.

Include placeholder text in your links since you can open the HTML page on a browser without serving it and see how the UI renders.

Make sure to post the full stack trace.  If you scroll down in the trace, you will find more helpful information.